# Powershell function that creates a array by input

Tags: arrays, function, powershell

I'm quite new to Powershell and working on a little project with functions.
What I'm trying to do is creating a function that takes 2 arguments.
The first argument ($Item1) decides the size of the array, the second argument ($Item2) decides the value of the indexes.

So if I write: $addToArray 10 5
I need the function to create a array with 10 indexes and the value 5 in each of them. The second argument would also have to take "text" as a value.

This is my code so far.

```
$testArray = @();

$indexSize = 0;

function addToArray($Item1, $Item2)

{

while ($indexSize -ne $Item1)

{

        $indexSize ++;    
    }

    Write-host "###";

    while ($Item2 -ne $indexSize)
    {
        $script:testArray += $Item2;
        $Item2 ++;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Kind regards
Dennis Berntsson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish that, here's a straightforward one (long version):

```
function addToArray($Item1, $Item2)
{
    $arr = New-Object Array[] $Item1

    for($i=0; $i -lt $arr.length; $i++)
    {
        $arr[$i]=$Item2
    }

    $arr
}

addToArray 10 5
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this, it helps me get a increased understanding of Powershell.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another possibility:

```
function addToArray($Item1, $Item2)
 {
   @($Item2) * $Item1
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

And another one.

```
function addToArray($Item1, $Item2) {
    #Counts from 1 to your $item1 number, and for each time it outputs the $item2 value.
    (1..$Item1) | ForEach-Object {
        $Item2
    }
}

#Create array with 3 elements, all with value 2 and catch/save it in the $arr variable
$arr = addToArray 3 2

#Testing it (values under $arr is output)
$arr
2
2
2
```